# Getting error for "from" using update query

Tags: mysql

```
select email,test_status,candidate_id,user_id from candidate_tests,candidate_candidates,users where candidate_tests.candidate_id=candidate_candidates.id and candidate_candidates.user_id=users.id;

update candidate_tests set candidate_tests.test_status='completed' from users as U inner join candidate_candidates as cc on candidate_candidates.user_id=users.id  inner join candidate_tests as ct on  candidate_tests.candidate_id=candidate_candidates.id where users.email='abcd@efgh.com';
```

error is: from is not an valid input at this position.
What is wrong with this query?

Answer (score 0):

Your update syntax is wrong. It must be:

```
update candidate_tests  as ct  inner join candidate_candidates as cc
 on  ct.candidate_id=cc.id
inner join  users as U 
 on cc.user_id=U.id  and  u.email='abcd@efgh.com'
set candidate_tests.test_status='completed'
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the UPDATE and JOIN syntax reference:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

You are putting the join in the wrong place

```
        UPDATE users as U 
    INNER JOIN candidate_candidates as cc 
            ON candidate_candidates.user_id=users.id 
    INNER JOIN candidate_tests as ct 
            ON candidate_tests.candidate_id=candidate_candidates.id 
           SET candidate_tests.test_status='completed' 
         WHERE users.email='abcd@efgh.com';
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use 'from' inside an update query. Please change your query to

```
update candidate_tests  as ct  inner join candidate_candidates as cc
 on  ct.candidate_id=cc.id
inner join  users as U 
 on cc.user_id=U.id  and  u.email='abcd@efgh.com'
set candidate_tests.test_status='completed'
```

**[REFERENCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)**